# A cpp error, an unintialized local Variable 'MemoryInformation'?

Tags: c++, memory

```
class CheckClass {
public:
    VOID Bypass() {
        DWORD START = (DWORD)GetModuleHandle(NULL);
        DWORD OFFSET = START + 0x1000;
        MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION MemoryInformation;
        CCLOCATION = Utility.FindPatternInMemory((unsigned 
        char*)OFFSET, MemoryInformation.RegionSize + OFFSET, (unsigned 
        char*)"\xCC\xCC\xCC\xCC", "xxxx");
        AddVectoredExceptionHandler(1, CallHandle);
    }
};
```

Basically, MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION MemoryInformation, throws an error `unintialized local Variable 'MemoryInformation'`

How could I fix that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm guessing it's doesn't really "throw" an error, but really, you haven't initialized the structure before using it. Aggregates in C++ don't magically get reasonable values in them when declared, you have to set things in them. What are you trying to do?

Comment: By *initializing* it? What is the value of e.g. `MemoryInformation.RegionSize` supposed to be? And do you really need the whole `MemoryInformation` object just to pass this value into the `FindPatternInMemory` function?

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel excuse my stupidity, All I had to do was to intialize it as a table, thanks for trying to help.

Comment: On another note, please don't tag multiple programming languages, unless the question really involves multiple languages.

Comment: `MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION` is meant to be passed to stuff like `VirtualQuery`. You're missing a step here.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel I updated the code, so you could see what I am trying to do.

Comment: `MemoryInformation.RegionSize` is not being assigned any value before it is used in `MemoryInformation.RegionSize + OFFSET`